# Wrong value being passed for unsigned long int in C++

Tags: c++

I have a program which takes an `unsigned long int` as an input, and all subsequent functions should receive the value as such.

In the `main` function, however, when 18446744073709551557 is entered, it is returned as 34359738363435973836, and when the value is passed to another function, it is seen as 3435973836.

How come this happens?

**EDIT:**

Main function is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    // initalise variables
    std::list<unsigned long int> results;
    unsigned long int n;

    // request user input
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "You entered: " << n << std::endl;

    // populate results list
    results = primeFactors(n);
    results.sort();

    // display results
    std::cout << "Factors for " << n << " are: ";
    for (int i : results)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Function the value gets passed into:

```
std::list<unsigned long int> primeFactors(unsigned long int n)
{
    // initialise variables
    std::list<unsigned long int> factors;
    bool complete = false;
    unsigned long int ans1 = 0;
    unsigned long int ans2 = 0;

    std::cout << n;
```

(There's a lot of code in the second function, so I haven't included it all)

Comment: Are you sure you're not exceeding ULONG_MAX?

Comment: @Bathsheba I've checked so many times, and it shouldn't be

Comment: @cse I've added the snippet as an edit

Comment: @RobDudley: What is sizeof(unsigned long int) on your platform?

Comment: `for (int i : results)` - why int?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Downvote converted to upvote. The question is now answerable.

Comment: Change `unsigned long int` to `unsigned long long int`. It appears that on your platform the size of an `unsigned long int` is 4.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The OP seems to cover that one off in the comments. For me the issue is the `int i`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I realised I was accidentally programming in 32-bit. I switched over to my Linux machine, and the sizeof(unsigned long int) is 8. I seem to be getting a floating point exception now though

Comment: Actually you should `#include <cstddef>` and drop `unsigned long int` and `int` alltogether and replace them with `uint64_t`. hen your program will be portable and correct.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Unfortunately, this is part of a project and it's specified that I must use unsigned long int :(

Comment: @RobDudley then at least don't mix `unsigned long int` and `int`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks, I've swapped out all of the 'int' variables

Comment: @Michael - "portable and correct" *on platforms that provide `uint64_t`*, since that's an optional type.  But still better that quietly truncating.  Other alternatives include checking the `failbit` flag (C++11 or newer) using `uint_fast64_t` instead, or reading as a string to convert with error-checking (e.g. `std::strtoull()`).

Comment: @Rob, "*There's a lot of code in the second function, so I haven't included it all*" is the reason we ask you to **create a [mcve] of your problem**.  I recommend you do that (and consider checking the result of `std::cin::operator>>()`).

Answer (score 2):

Your input number is far too large to store as an unsigned long int.

You can view the limits for various types [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

I would suggest looking into using a library that can handle arbitrarily large numbers such as [Boost.multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 18446744073709551557 is a valid unsigned long int.

It crosses the limit already. 
The limit of c++ datatype are [here...](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

Try the value between limits. If then also doesn't work help us to see the code snippets and to detect the bugs.